# SQL Date Diff disregarding Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to make a select, where the users birthday(date field) is less than 30 days.
what is the best way to to do it? i tried datediff, but i don't know how to put the year aside.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function with `dayofyear` datepart value.

**EDIT:** honestly, there is a boundary issue in my previous answer (many thanks to [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)): e.g. `2010-12-25` and `2011-01-07` => the difference should be less then 30 days, but `DATEPART(dayofyear, @date) - DATEPART(dayofyear, [Birthday]) < 30` condition would skip this record. So I added an additional contition to my answer:

```
DATEPART(dy, @d) - DATEPART(dy, [Birthday]) < 30 OR
(
   DATEPART(mm, @d) = 12 AND
   DATEPART(dy, DATEADD(m, 1, @d)) - DATEPART(dy, DATEADD(m, 1, [Birthday])) < 30
)
```

it adds one month to the each date in the case when the month part of the first date is December and compares the difference.

Comment: Doesn't that have boundary issues around December/January?

Answer (score 2):

A common way is to compose a formatted date, as text, and replace the year with the current year; and parse back into a date. Apply datediff on that.

If you find out datediff returns something negative thus the birthday of this year is in the past, add 1 year, and try again. This is for the time period around New Year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.CheckBirthDay
WHERE (CASE WHEN YEAR(BirthDay) <= YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN DATEDIFF(DD,BirthDay,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) END < 30 )
```